# Completely hide armature influence temporarily

Tags: modeling, rigging, armature

I've modeled and rigged a character, however I want to model different sets of clothing for that character.

Because I'm using IK on the bones, even if I reset all the bone's positions via a -> a -> w -> Clear User Transforms (All), the character's arms and legs are slightly offset from the model's default position in edit mode.

How do I completely remove the visual influence of the armature from the character without having to parent it again (because I have custom weight paint fixes I don't want to lose)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, I found the answer to my question. The armature transforms are treated as a "modifier" on the character mesh. All I had to do was deselect the eye icon for that modifier.

[image]